# How do i match a string by following Regular Expression

Tags: regex

Here is my regular expression:

```
(?is)(\b\w+\b)\s*\bas\b\s*\bdisplay_text\b
```

I need to match "field2" in the following two strings:

1. `SELECT DISTINCT field1 AS value, field2 AS display_text`
2. `SELECT DISTINCT replace(field1, ',', '/') AS value, replace(field2, ',', '/') AS display_text`

Using the above regular expression "field2" is only a match from the 1st string. So I need a regular expression that can match "field2" from both strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an optional non-capturing group.

```
(?is)(\b\w+\b)(?:,\s*'[^']*',\s*'[^']*'\))?\s*\bas\b\s*\bdisplay_text\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fZ6uH2/1)

Comment: (?is)(\b\w+\b)(?:,\s*'[^']*',\s*'[^']*'\))?\s*\bas\b\s*\bdisplay_text\b
Above regular expression currently matching "field2" from the following strings.
 
1. SELECT DISTINCT field1 AS value, field2 AS display_text
2. SELECT DISTINCT replace(field1, ',', '/') AS value, replace(field2, ',', '/') AS display_text

I need a regular expression that can match "field2" from 1st statement and "replace(field2, ',', '/')" from 2nd statement.